# Proper declaration of an empty Django PostgreSQL JSONField default value in migration file

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm a little lost interpreting [Django's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) explanation of applying   a default value to a PostgreSQL JSONField:

> If you give the field a default, ensure it’s a callable such as `dict` (for an empty default) or a callable that returns a `dict` (such as a function). Incorrectly using `default={}` creates a mutable default that is shared between all instances of JSONField.

So in my model file I've declared the default as such

```
foo = JSONField(default=dict())
```

however when I generate the migration operation for the new field this is the result

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='bar',
    name='foo',
    field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(default={}))
```

I'm just not sure whether or not this result is in accordance with the documentation's suggestion. Is this valid, or should I modify the generated default to call `dict()`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A *callable* is an object `x` that *can* be called, hence `x()` is valid, and will not raise an error because it is not callable (although there can be errors during the call, for example because the function somewhere yields an error).

`dict()` is actually completely *equivalent* to `{}`, that is not a callable, since `{}()`, will not result in constructing anything. But **`dict`** itself on the other hand is a reference to the `dict` class, and if we call it, we construct a *new* `dict`. So we should write it like:

```
# no brackets! We do not make a call, but pass the callable
foo = JSONField(default=dict)
```

So we do **not** call the `dict` class, we pass a *reference* to the class, and such classes are callable: if you call them, you typically construct a new instance (although this behavior can be changed).

Passing the callable is of vital importance here, since otherwise Django will each time use a reference to the *same* dictionary. As a result changes to one of the dictionaries will change the others that change the reference. If you store the dictionary and reload it, then this will be a different dictionary, but as long as you constructed two models, during the same Python run, these would be the same objects.

If you however pass a function, the function will be called, and thus produce two *different* objects, both empty dictionaries. But changes to the first dictionary will not reflect in the second one.

The same holds if you for instance would want to initialize a JSON field with a dictionary that contains data, instead of writing <s>`default={'a': 4}`</s>, one has to define it like:

```
def default_somemodel_dict():
    return {'a': 4}

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    foo = JSONField(default=default_somemodel_dict)
```

Comment: @thebjorn: the minimal change is probably "*A* callable", thanks for noting :)

Comment: The parenthesis in paragraph 1 seems unnecessary. "we do not call the dict function" -> we do not call dict (might be confusing to call dict a function after calling it a class?)

Comment: Great answer. This should be included in the official docs for JSONField